# performSelector afterDelay with multiple arguments error

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4, unrecognized-selector, performselector

I´m having some problems with performSelector method on this code:

This method are in other class called "JSONMethods":

```
+(void)sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments:(NSArray *)myArgs {
[self sendPostMsg:[myArgs objectAtIndex:0]:[myArgs objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

Then, on another class I have the call:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"Loading...";

JSONMethods *methods = [[JSONMethods alloc]init];
NSArray *arguments = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"http://localhost/promos/txFirmas.php",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sensor=%d",tableViewNumber], nil];
[methods performSelector:@selector(sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments:)
           withObject:arguments
           afterDelay:3.0];

NSString *tit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sign: %d",tableViewNumber];
self.title = tit;
}
```

I would like wait until the "sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments:" finish for change the title, how I can make it?
When I test this, mi app crash and show me this by console:

```
2012-08-17 12:09:15.966 MapaProject[524:11603] -[JSONMethods sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c85b70
2012-08-17 12:09:15.968 MapaProject[524:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[JSONMethods sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c85b70'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x133a022 0x2016cd6 0x133bcbd 0x12a0ed0 0x12a0cb2 0xa1c85d 0x130e936 0x130e3d7 0x1271790 0x1270d84 0x1270c9b 0x15db7d8 0x15db88a 0xf6626 0x236d 0x20c5)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `+(void)sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments:(NSArray *)myArgs`

to `-(void)sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments:(NSArray *)myArgs`

or even better change

`[methods performSelector:@selector(sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments:) withObject:arguments afterDelay:3.0];`

to `[[methods class] performSelector:@selector(sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments:)
           withObject:arguments
           afterDelay:3.0];`

Comment: Perfect! works fine :), one more thing, then how i can wait until performSelector finish for continue the code?

Comment: you wanna continue program execution immediately after sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments method is over?

Comment: yes, when sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments returns, i wanna change the title of the view from "loading..." to other string, but now the title change before the method return

Comment: put call for the next method at the end of sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments

Comment: but... this method I use it for more things, and make the change at the end, will change the titles of more views

Comment: so make a bool flag at the end of sendPostMsgWithMultipleArguments -     if (calledForFirstTime) [self doSomething]; else [self doSomethingElse];

Comment: true! Sometimes I try to make things very difficult hehe. Thanks!!

Comment: or just `[JSONMethods performSelector...`

Answer (score 0):

NSArray * mutArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber   numberWithInt:2], nil]

[self performSelector:@selector(loadMore:) withObject:mutArray afterDelay:1.9];

```
-(void)loadMore:(NSArray *)array
{
 NSNumber * myNumber = [array objectAtIndex:0];
 NSNumber * myNumber2 = [array objectAtIndex:1];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**In swift 3**

You can make dictionary to save multiple arguments and pass it with the selector

```
let argumentsDict = ["arg1Key": arg1Value, "arg2Key": arg2Value] as [String : Any]

perform(#selector(selectorWithMultipleArg), with: argumentsDict, afterDelay: 3.0)
```

And inside the selector function, take out values using guard and use them. I am using 2 different type arguments to explain better .i.e. Int and String

```
func selectorWithMultipleArg(_ arguments: [String: Any]) {

    guard let arg1Value = arguments["arg1Key"] as? Int else {
        fatalError("Invalid value 1")
    }

    guard let arg2Value = arguments["arg2Key"] as? String else {
        fatalError("Invalid value 2")
    }
    print("Value 1: \(arg1Value)")
    print("Value 2: \(arg2Value)")

}
```

I hope this would help you